Can an index can be used for list/array properties in Memgraph?
I'd like to know if an index can be used for list/array properties. Say I have nodes that look like this: (n {members:['a','b']}) Will an index help me find nodes where 'a' is a member? Or will indexes only work on scalar data types?

You can set it up and it will be faster then filtering over all nodes in the graph, but it won't be as fast as using it on a scalar property type, since it still needs to go over that each list.
